# Keep getting wrong answer in program that converts binary to decimal

Tags: java

For homework, I have to write a program in java that converts a binary number that the user inputs (n) into a decimal number. I'm not allowed to use any cheat functions and stuff. This is the code for the static method I have so far:

```
public static int binarytodecimal(String n) {
      int answer=0; 
      int digit=0; 
      int multiplier=1;
      char index=n.charAt(digit);
      int length=n.length();
      while (index=='0' || index=='1' && digit<=length) {
          if (index=='1') {
              answer+=multiplier;
              multiplier*=2;
              digit+=1;
          }
          else {
              multiplier*=2;
              digit+=1;
          }
      }
      return answer;
  }
```

For example, if n was 1, I keep getting 3 when the answer should be 1. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you should iterate through n in reverse mode (test something like n="1101" and you will see) then inside your loop read bits at each position

```
public static int binarytodecimal(String n) {
        int answer = 0;
        int digit = n.length();
        int multiplier = 1;
        while (digit > 0) {
            char index = n.charAt(digit - 1);
            if (index == '1') {
                answer += multiplier;
                multiplier *= 2;
                digit--;
            } else {
                multiplier *= 2;
                digit--;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: My pleasure. Glad i could help.